# Creating a clickable grid in Processing 3

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, processing

I'm trying to make a grid of squares that change their fill (from black to white and vice-versa) when clicked. I'm able to turn the entire grid on or off currently, but I'm unable to figure out how to specify which particular square should be toggled when the mouse clicks within its borders. I've created buttons using mouseX and mouseY coordinates before, but they were for specific objects that I could adjust manually. I can't figure out how to do this using for loops and arrays.

I've been told to create a boolean array and pass the value of that array to the grid array, but again, I don't know how to specify which part of the array it needs to go to. For example, how do I change the fill value of square [6][3] upon mousePressed?

Here is my code so far:

```
int size = 100;
int cols = 8;
int rows = 5;
boolean light = false;
int a;
int b;

void setup() { 
  size (800, 600);
  background (0);
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
  light = !light;

  int[][] box = new int[cols][rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      box[i][j] = i;
      int a = i*100;
      int b = j*100;


      if (light == true) {
        fill(255);
      } else {
        fill(0);
      }
      rect(a, b, 100, 100);

      println(i, j);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do some arithmetic involving `rows, cols, width, height, mouseX, mouseY` to find the center of the square which is closest to `(mouseX, mouseY)`. Get out some scrap paper and figure out how to do it by hand for various choices. Once you understand how it works, code it.

Comment: @JohnColeman I can figure out how to locate the mouse cursor without any issues. The part I'm stuck on is figuring out how to specify that a particular section of my array should be changed depending on the position of the cursor. Or perhaps, specifying that a shape should be changed defined by a specific section of my grid array.

Comment: Keep a boolean array (say `clicked`) with one entry per square in your grid. When you detect that a click has registered in a certain square (something which you say that you can do with no issue`, toggle the corresponding entry in the `clicked` array. When drawing the squares, check the array when deciding on the fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are currently recreating the entire board whenever the mouse is pressed. You must retain that info between mouse clicks, so make `box` a global array up there with the others. Further, it's sufficient to make it a `boolean` array if all you care about is the on/off state of each square:

```
boolean[][] isSquareLight = new boolean[cols][rows];
```

Instead of

```
if (light == true) {
```

you should then just check

```
if (isSquareLight[i][j] == true) {
```

(note that the `== true` is redundant).

Now, you've already written code that finds the coordinates for each box: You're passing it to `rect`!

```
rect(a, b, 100, 100);
```

All that is left to do is check whether the mouse is inside this rect, i.e. whether `mouseX` is between `a` and `a+100` (and similar for `mouseY`) - if that's the case, then the user clicked in the box given by the current (`i`, `j`), so you can just negate `isSquareLight[i][j]` (before checking it like above) and it will work.

There are ways to calculate this without looping through the entire grid every time, but maybe the above helps you find the path yourself instead of just getting the code made for you.

PS: The `int a; int b;`  at the top does nothing and can be removed. You are using the local variables `a` and `b` in your function, which is correct.

Comment: I'm answering the question by showing the way to the solution. I think each step is now small enough that it makes for a good learning experience, and the answer is close enough to the original code that (together with the explanations) it becomes clear how one would have found these steps without help. By the way, it was not me who downvoted your answer. Edit: Other comment was removed.